# Java how to form a structured list of numbers

Tags: java

what I'am looking for:

```
------------------------
[1][11][25][34][44][55]
------------------------
[5][15][23][35][43][56]
------------------------
[9][19][27][36][42][58]
------------------------
```

my array:

```
ArrayList arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41 etc...upto 100];
```

so what I want to do is to sort this array like in the diagram above, the first vertical column should be less than 10, the next column should be more than 10, but less than 20, the next should be more than 20, but less than 30, how to realize than using array or ArrayList in Java?

Comment: Nice homework. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far ?

Comment: You should write code that does that.

Comment: I really don't have an idea on how to this sorting, please any hint?, can you give me a little example on how to do that?, the rest I will write by myself

Comment: Does your array contains **always** all the numbers between 1 and 100 ? Or it can be random ?

Comment: they may be random sorted, but always will have numbers from 1 to 100, just only randomly sorted

Comment: So, can it be
`[1] [11] [21] [31] [41] [51]
[2] ........` like that?

Comment: Is this about sorting or about formatting the output? For sorting look at: Collections.sort(List<T>)

Comment: use `<` and `>` to compare the numbers, use `arr[n]` to access the `nth` number in the array, use `System.out.println()` to output the result

Comment: Use `Collections.sort(yourList)` to sort it and then that should be easy to build such an array.

Comment: its a random array of results numbers, yes it may be of any sequence

Comment: I've used that Collections.sort, but it doesn't have the logic I need, my head is blowing can anyone write a little sample of code, the rest I will complete by myself, I just need an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a double array, or ArrayList of ArrayLists, would help here. Your first index would be the 'bin' you wanted numbers to fall into: 0-10 11-19, 20-29, etc, and the second index (or List) would be the new value. Iterate through your array, determine the bin, add it.

If you always had the numbers 1-100, a double array `int[10][10]` would suffice, but if you didn't know the inputs, having a List would be better (so it could more easily grow).

Comment: great thats what I've needed, a double array